# Accessing class of class

Tags: c++, class

```
Class A{
public:
      MyVec<A> test; //problem  error: ‘MyVec’ does not name a type
};

Class B{
public:
      template<typename Obj>
      Class MyVec{
           //some methods...
      };
private:
      MyVec<A> test1; //ok
};
```

Compiler complains about the line where test is defined.

Comment: B::MyVec<A> test;  // otherwise it's looking for MyVec<A> in the global namespace.

Comment: The code you have posted is not C++. Please post the real code that causes the problem.

Comment: But this time it complains B does not have a type.

Comment: You need to change the order of the classes in the file: b first, then a

Comment: Ok, it was problem of ordering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't define or even declare `MyVec` before the definition of A. This makes it impossible for the type to be used in A. This is because of the order of declarations.

Answer (score 1):

`MyVec`'s full name is `B::MyVec`. The `B::` part is optional when you're inside `B`.

Comment: move Class A's definition below Class B

Comment: @asami You got bitten in the ass by C++'s compilation model. A C++ compiler only does a single pass, which means `B` must be declared before `A` if you want to use `B` in `A`.

Comment: i realized that as soon as i posted the comment :) but it's a dilemma. He is using B::MyVec inside A that means it shud be defined before A